# How to slide images to the left using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried sliding two images from right to left. The slide is working but only displaying the first image. Please what's the cause? This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var n=0;
  var nmax=2;
  function timer()
  {
    window.setInterval(function ()
    {
      n+=1;
      if(n>nmax)
      {
        n=0;
        $('#slideImage').css('left','0');
      }

      $('#slideImage').css('left',(n)*(1366)*(-1)+'px');
    },2500);
  }
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        timer();
    });
</script>
```

`css`

```
.wn_p { height: 400px; width: 1366px; float: left; }
.w_n { height: 400px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: #09C; }
.w_n2 { height: 400px; width: 2732px; margin-right: auto; 
margin-left: auto; position: relative; display: inline-table; 
transition: linear 0.75s 0.2s; -moz-transition: linear 0.75s 0.2s; 
-webkit-transition: linear 0.75s 0.2s; }
```

and here is `html`

```
<div class="w_n"> 
<div class="w_n2" id="slideImage"> 
<div class="hd_p"> 
<img name="shift" src="image/bn2.jpg" class="wn_p" /> 
<div class="des_p">The company maintains high quality standard in all its operations. With high production capacity, the policy thrust is to continue to provide cost-effective, affordable, local alternatives of life saving drugs to the teaming population.
</div> 
</div> 
<img name="shift" src="image/bn3.jpg" class="wn_p" />
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: use [.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for smooth effects.

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery anyway, why not use its [animate](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=animate) function?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.wn_p').animate({left: '-200px'}, {duration: 2500});
});
```

You can set a lot of options, so if you show some html and elaborate on your needs, we could better match the result you're expecting.

The fact only one image is shown could be a CSS thing. You're using an ID, but should use a class if there's more than one image.

Edit: I changed the selector to the class you added. You propably figured that out by now, but it should work this way.

Comment: this is the html <div class="w_n">
 <div class="w_n2" id="slideImage">
     <div class="hd_p">
         <img name="shift" src="image/bn2.jpg" class="wn_p" />
            <div class="des_p">The company maintains high quality standard in all its operations. With high production capacity, the policy thrust is to continue to provide cost-effective, affordable, local alternatives of life saving drugs to the teaming population.</div>
        </div>
     <img name="shift" src="image/bn3.jpg" class="wn_p" />
    </div>
</div>

Comment: and these are the css .wn_p {
 height: 400px;
 width: 1366px;
 float: left;
}
.w_n {
 height: 400px;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #09C;
}
.w_n2 {
 height: 400px;
 width: 2732px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
 transition: linear 0.75s 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: linear 0.75s 0.2s;
 -webkit-transition: linear 0.75s 0.2s;
}

Comment: @user3021144 I updated the selector to use the class you added. Does it work as expected now?

Answer (score 1):

For lots of cycle image effects it might be worthwhile checking out this jQuery Cycle Plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

THis is a basic pager that might be of interest to start you off: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/pager.php

Here are lots of demos that might help: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var n=0,switcher=1; // Note change 
  var nmax=2;
  function timer()
  {
    window.setInterval(function ()
    {
    if(switcher){ // Note change 
      n+=1;
    }
    else{ // Note change 
    n--; // Note change 
    } // Note change 
      if(n>=nmax) // Note change 
      {
       switcher=0; // Note change 
      }
      if(n<=0) // Note change 
     {
     switcher=1; // Note change 
     }

      $('#slideImage').animate({left:''+(n)*(1366)*(-1)+'px'},500); // Note change 
    },2500);
  }
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        timer();
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.des_p{height: 400px; width: 1366px;float: left; }
.wn_p { height: 400px; width: 1366px; float: left; }
.w_n { height: 400px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: #09C; }
.w_n2 { height: 400px; width: 2732px; margin-right: auto; 
margin-left: auto; position: relative; display: inline-table; 
transition: linear 0.75s 0.2s; -moz-transition: linear 0.75s 0.2s; 
-webkit-transition: linear 0.75s 0.2s; } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="w_n"> 
<div class="w_n2" id="slideImage"> 
<div class="hd_p"> 
<img name="shift" src="image/bn2.jpg" class="wn_p" /> 
<div class="des_p">The company maintains high quality standard in all its operations. With high production capacity, the policy thrust is to continue to provide cost-effective, affordable, local alternatives of life saving drugs to the teaming population.
</div> 
</div> 
<img name="shift" src="image/bn3.jpg" class="wn_p" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:2732px;" /><!-- Note change -->
 </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

actually  problem was not in your `js` but it was in your `css` due to low height overflow was `hidden`..

i fixed that by using `positioning` of element in `css`..

according to your last comment i've updated answer for sliding images in both direction.

please pay attention in the lines marked by `Note change` at end.
hope it'll  help  you. cheers !!

Comment: @user3021144 changed my answer and checked that too, have a look at that.

Comment: it worked, bt after the end of slide instead of starting with the first image it'll slide in the opposite direction with the last image. please what can I do?

Comment: it worked but after a circle of slide an empty space is left before another slide.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slideImage').animate({left: '-200px'},2500);
});
```